# Javascript object does not see internal function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript prototype style class like this ...

```
const _FormValidator = function(fieldDefinition){

  // check the regEx is actually a regEx
  const regEx = fieldDefinition.regEx;
  const regExType = Object.prototype.toString.call(regEx);
  if (regExType === '[object RegExp]'){
    this.regEx = regEx;
  }

  // just make the mandatory property true or false.
  this.isMandatory = false;
  if (fieldDefinition.mandatory){
    self.isMandatory = true;
  }
}

_FormValidator.prototype.validateRegEx = function(value){
  const regEx = this.regEx;
  if (!regEx){
    return true;
  }
  return regEx.test(value);
}

_FormValidator.prototype.validateMandatory = function(value){
  if (!value){
    return !this.mandatory;
  }
  return true;
}

_FormValidator.prototype.validate = function(value){
  const validRegEx = this.validateRegEx(value);
  const validMandatory = this.validateMandatory(value);
  return validRegEx && validMandatory;
}

export const FormValidator = _FormValidator;
```

The FormValidator is imported and used as a constructor in side a Meteor (1.3) helper for a Blaze Template.

However I get the response `validator.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: this.validateRegEx is not a function`. I'm struggling to figure out why. Can anyone help?

Comment: How exactly is `.validate()` being called? The problem is *probably* that `this` is not a reference to a `FormValidator` instance. That would happen if (for example) the `validate` function reference were used as an event handler without a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Okay with the help of Pointy's comment I figured the issue myself. Solution below.

This is what I used to do to call validate (inside a Meteor Blaze template):

I initialize the validator in the `onCreated` method like this:

```
  const validator = new FormValidator(instance.data.field);
  instance.validate = validator.validate;
```

Then I used to call it as `instance.validate(value)`.

I have now changed this to:

```
  const validator = new FormValidator(instance.data.field);
  instance.validator = validator;
```

And call this as `instance.validator.validate(value)` which resolves the issue. 
Sorry I'm still hitting utter confusion when dealing with this in javascript.